# Question about a demonstration of the autocorrelation theorem

Tags: autocorrelation

I’m stuck on this demonstration.

It says:

> If $x'$ is held constant, $dx=dy$

How can $x’$ be constant? Shouldn't $x’$ be a variable?

[image]

Comment: Hi: There are two different variables being integrated over in the definition of the fourier transform of  the autocorrelation function. So, while you're integrating over $x$, $x^{\prime}$ is viewed as a constant.

Comment: It depends on the fact tht there is an other integral $dx'$?

Comment: yes, because while you are integrating over $x$, $x^\prime$ is held constant so it's derivative is zero in the $y = x + x^\prime$ equation.